# Vertica Connection Error: [Vertica][VJDBC](100071) from DBeaver

Tags: vertica, dbeaver

Am trying to connect vertica from DBeaver, but am getting below connection error. Initially it was working fine, but suddenly its throwing connection error.

Error Message:

```
    [Vertica][VJDBC](100071) GSS authentication failed due to problems establishing a TGT with JAAS using configuration verticajdbc; reason: Message stream modified (41). 
  Message stream modified (41)
  Message stream modified (41)
```

I am not able to establish the connection now. Can anyone please help me on it.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see with vertica users struggling to connect relate to the drivers used or where the host has changed. Have you updated vertica recently or has there been a change to the host name are just a couple of things you should check.

Sorry I cant be more specific its hard to troubleshoot when I dont have all the information.

Thanks

Comment: it was drivers version issue. now its resolved. Thank you